# FInd the area of the quadrilateral $ABCD.$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

A point moving around a circle $x^2+y^2+8x+4y-5=0$ with center $C$ broke away from it either at the point $A$ or at the point $B$ on the circle and moved along a tangent to the circle passing through the point $D(3,-3).$FInd the area of the quadrilateral $ABCD.$

---

We can take the point $D$ either on the tangent passing through point $A$ or the tangent passing through point $B$.I took $D$ on the tangent passing through point $A$.Area of quadrilateral $ABCD=$area of triangle $ACD+$ area of triangle $BCD.$I found the area of triangle $ACD=\frac{25}{2}$,but i cannot find the area of triangle $BCD.$

Please help me.

Comment: D must be where the tangents intersect

Answer (score 0):

1. complete the squares to calculate the co-ordinates of the point C and the radius of the circle.

   compute the length CD

   Use the fact that the angles at A and B are right angles to calculate the lengths BD and AD

   Area = $\frac 12 AC \times AD + \frac 12 BC \times BD$

Comment: Why D is assumed to be at the intersection of the tangents,any particular reason,Sir?@WW1

Comment: either - "Sometimes I get off the subway at station A, sometimes station B, in either case I go straight home"  Means to a native english speaker that in both cases  I go straight home. @Vnod Kumar Punia